# CSS Marquee With Fade In/Out Effect

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a CSS marquee whose text fades in from the right edge and fades out on the left edge. Only the letters on the edges should turn transparent. I'd call it an "opacity mask" that is feathered onto the left/right edges.

I can find CSS marquee code samples but none with such a fade in/out effect. I'd also like the background to be completely transparent, with just the text having the edge effects.

I've tried adding a gradient to the container but, in hind sight, that doesn't seem to be the right path. Below is the code I've come up with thus far. Please assist, thanks!

@Bernard Borg: I've updated my code with the second new sample. Other than this not using opacity - *and therefore being A) dependent on being hardcoded to the underlying background color and B) only working on a solid background* - this is acceptable for my use case. Thanks! (Any idea how to cover the marquee with opacity rather than a color?)

```css
div#container {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e6e9eb;
}

div#marquee-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

p#marquee {
  animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
}
            
@keyframes scroll-left {
  0%   {transform: translateX( 140%)}
  100% {transform: translateX(-140%)}
}

div#marquee-cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(230, 233, 235, 1) 0%, rgba(230, 233, 235, 0) 15%, rgba(230, 233, 235, 0) 85%, rgba(230, 233, 235, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="marquee-container">
    <p id="marquee">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
    <div id="marquee-cover"/> <!--thanks Bernard Borg-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The 15% and 85% refer to the percentage completion of the animation timeline, not the percentage of the text the opacity change will apply to.

Comment: I get what you're asking now. This willl take some time to figure out but it's interesting so I will help you

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I probably could have worded it better. In other words, I want to apply a gradual opacity mask to the first and last 15% of the DIV, horizontally. Apparently there is no such thing as a CSS "opacity mask" according to Google, though, so I'm probably still using the wrong terminology.

Comment: That's a great way to put it - masking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For anyone coming to this question in the future - the answer to this question was a joint effort. Find the answer in the question.

This is the closest I was able to get to your updated question;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#marquee-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

p#marquee {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 80%;
  animation: scroll-left 5s linear infinite;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#first-cover,
#second-cover {
  height: 100vw;
  backdrop-filter: opacity(50%);
  width: 30vw;
  z-index: 100;
}

#first-cover {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2));
}

#second-cover {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2));
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(130%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-130%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="marquee-container">
    <div id="first-cover"></div>
    <p id="marquee">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
    <div id="second-cover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason backdrop-filter (specifically with opacity) isn't doing anything. Weird.

Edit:

You could probably define an image for the background of the marquee (with gradients on each side) and then use [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) in some way to fade the text. Perhaps I'm overcomplicating this. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Comment: Thanks again! Ah, you're adding covers as the masks instead of adding opacity. Yeah, that could work, why didn't I think of that? lol. I'd prefer to add covers of opacity but, if that's not possible, this should get the job done too. Thanks! I've updated the original post with this concept applied in a way that produces my intended result.

Now if I can just figure out how to calculate the marquee to start with the first word and end with the last word... Currently it ends with a ton of white space rather than on the last word.

Comment: No problem. Your updated question is exactly what I was trying to do. Good job!

Comment: Use this values to fix your issue: `0% {
    transform: translateX(100%)
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%)
  }`

Comment: High five, then! We did it, lol, mostly with your help. You just got those new transform values from trial and error, right? My problem is that I plan to use this framework for various messages that will vary in length, so I will need a math-based method of calculating this - rather than trial and error - so that it can be standardized to work no matter what message I feed it.

Comment: Yea trial and error

Comment: I think I should be able to use the parent scrollWidth and the paragraph scrollWidth to calculate that! Start @ parent scrollWidth + a buffer, end @ negative (paragraph scrollWidth + a buffer).

Answer (score 1):

Animate the opacity property (cleaned up the code for better readability);

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div#marquee-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 85%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}

p#marquee {
  text-align: right;
  animation: scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  20% {
     opacity: 1;
  }
  
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-80%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: black; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div id="marquee-container">
    <p id="marquee">Testing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Side note: You don't need vendor prefixes for animation anymore.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like we're getting closer. I still have a slight issue. I'll update my question with the new code.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
}

div#marquee-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 85%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}

p#marquee {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  --opacity: 0;
  moz-animation:     scroll-left 1s  linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-left 1s  linear infinite;
  animation:         scroll-left 10s linear infinite;
}
            
  @-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
    0%   {-moz-transform: translateX( 100%);}
    100% {-moz-transform: translateX(-100%);}
  }
            
  @-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
    0%   {-webkit-transform: translateX( 100%)}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%)}
  }
            
  @keyframes scroll-left {
    0%   {-moz-transform: translateX( 100%); -webkit-transform: translateX( 100%); transform: translateX( 100%); opacity: 0;}
    30%{
    opacity: 1;
    }
      60%{
    opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {-moz-transform: translateX(-100%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); transform: translateX(-100%);opacity: 0; }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="marquee-container">
    <p id="marquee">Testing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide details in your answer, not only code.